# Cant get text from textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

So, I need to get a string from a textbox to use in a backend program, but I'm unable to get it when im one the site, however it works if i set Text="Test1" prior, even though i change the text in the textbox, "Test1" always gets sent to to my function and works! (Talking about Box3)

Code to the text boxes below

```
                <div class="row">
                <form action="#" method="post" class="contact-form">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Box3" Text="Test1" runat="server" placeholder="Gamepin..."></asp:TextBox>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="Box2" runat="server" placeholder="Name  ..."></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="Box1" runat="server" placeholder="Amount ..."></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>
                    <div   >
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxREPLY"  runat="server" style="vertical-align: central" Text="YesNo" TextAlign="Left" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Funcactivate" class="button big green" value="Launch!"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

And my code to get textbox.text

```
        protected void Funcactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get textbox(s)
        string Game = Box1.Text;
        string Namepref = Box2.Text;
        string Amount = Box3.Text;
     }
```

Comment: Show the code where you set the value originally. And don't nest your forms. You should only have one form in ASP.NET Web Forms, and it should have the `runat="server"` attribute.

Comment: I haven't set the value, I use a placeholder. Alright I'll fix the form real quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving my form to only get the < asp:X, because i discovered that if the < asp:x was nested too deep within a ton of divs, it didnt work properly.

It may have been due to something else, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your button could work.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLaunch" runat="server" Text="Launch!" class="button big green" OnClick="Funcactivate" CausesValidation="False"/>
```

Comment: When doing this it doesnt seem to interact with my function at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web forms, you should be able to capture the text box entry in the  "if(!IsPostBack){...}" event and set it to a variable and use it in your "Funcactivate" method.

Hello Sleepwalker, here is a code sample that works for me, I am not using the isPostBack. I am also using an asp:button Instead of using an HTML input control.

```
 <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </div>


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string game = this.txtBox1.Text.ToString();
        string Namepref = this.txtBox2.Text.ToString();
        string Amount = this.txtBox3.Text.ToString(); //box3;
    }
```

Comment: Can you make an example code of this? Im not quite sure what to do.